# "React.CreateElement: type is invalid" after creating typings for an existing js module

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use [react-images](https://github.com/jossmac/react-images) in a typescript project. There is no `@types/react-images` package, so I am creating the typings myself. I have done this before for other packages with no problem. The process of creating declarations for existing javascript modules is described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries).

When I provide a simple `.d.ts` file like,

```
declare module 'react-images' {

  export default class Lightbox extends React.Component {

  }
}
```

And I import and use it in my project like this,

```
import Lightbox from 'react-images'

...

return (<Lightbox images={ images } onClose={ ():any => null } { ...defaultProps } />)
```

I get the following error in the browser:

```
warning.js:35 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

I'm wondering if anyone may be able to shed some light onto what I might be doing wrong here.

---

Typical solutions to this kind of problem include changing the way one includes a module from the `include MyModule` style to the `include { MyModule }`style. However, the module I am writing typings for declares a class like,

```
class Lightbox extends Component {
```

And exports it like,

```
export default Lightbox;
```

(see the [relevant file](https://github.com/jossmac/react-images/blob/master/src/Lightbox.js))

So I am importing it with the `import Lightbox from` style, to get the default export. Notably, when I try to log the imported object with `console.log` it is always undefined. This leads me to suspect that there is something up.

---

Currently my `.d.ts` file for react-images looks like,

```
declare module 'react-images' {
  import * as React from 'react'

  export interface ILightBoxImages {
    src: string,
    srcset?: any[],
    caption?: string | Element,
    thumbnail?: string,
  }

  export interface ILightBoxProps {
    images: ILightBoxImages[],
    onClose: () => void,

    backdropClosesModal?: boolean,
    closeButtonTitle?: string,
    currentImage?: number,
    customControls?: any[],
    enableKeyboardInput?: boolean,
    imageCountSeparator?: string,
    isOpen?: boolean,
    leftArrowTitle?: string,
    onClickImage?: any,
    onClickNext?: any,
    onClickPrev?: any,
    preloadNextImage?: boolean,
    rightArrowTitle?: string,
    showCloseButton?: boolean,
    showImageCount?: boolean,
    showThumbnails?: boolean,
    theme?: object,
    thumbnailOffset?: number,
    width?: number,
  }

  export default class Lightbox extends React.Component<ILightBoxProps, any> {

  }
}
```

as I have tried to build interfaces from the propTypes provided in the package.